# Android, How to disable lockscreen/screen timeout (API version independent)

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I need to disable lockscreen and set screentimeout to never not only in my app but for the phone generaly.

I tried to set the screentimeout to "-1", which worked e.g. on Android 2.3 but not on 4.2
Is there any way to do so?

```
Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, "-1");
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it in the xml layout file of each activity by adding
Android:screenOn="true"

Comment: I need this for the whole phone (other apps included) not just for my activities, thanks for reply thought.

Comment: Then you can do it using a wakeLock service. I didn't use it but is used for keeping phone awake. Here is a link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128126/service-wakelock

Comment: It is `android:keepScreenOn="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to check on 4.2 but the same code worked fine on 4.1.2 as long as I added the following permission -

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already have this in my manifest. I didn't test 4.1.2 but on 4.2 this solution doesn't work.